# Passing an argument with the alignment operator (&) to a macro within another aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, macros, align, matrices

I am trying to write macros for quickly formatting matrices in math mode. Here is a simple, working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pmat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
M = \pmat{1&0\\0&1}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

This also works if used *within* an aligned environment (a `table`, `align` environment, `cases` environment, etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pmat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
M &= \pmat{1&0\\0&1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Normally, within the `align` environment the `&` symbol tells LaTeX to start a new column, but since the matrix values are contained between `{}` group tokens, LaTeX does not attempt to parse the `1&0\\0&1` argument and thus everything works as it was intended.

Let's create a new macro that does not use the group tokens `{}` to denote the macro argument. For example, it is fairly common to use square brackets to group an argument as in this working example (try it!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bmat}[1][]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
M = \bmat[1&0\\0&1]
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

So far, so good. Here comes the problem! If I try to use my new macro `\bmat` *within* another aligned environment:

```
% DOES NOT WORK!!!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bmat}[1][]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
M &= \bmat[1&0\\0&1]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I get an error because LaTeX tries to interpret the `&` within the matrix argument as part of the outer `align` environment.

The difference between the way LaTeX treats the first macro `\pmat{}` and the second one `\bmat[]` is that the group tokens `{}` prevent LaTeX from parsing the argument contained within the curly braces until after the macro `\pmat` has been called. On the other hand, when LaTeX sees the `\bmat[arg]` macro, the argument is not surrounded by group tokens and so LaTeX tries to parse it *before* getting eaten up by `\bmat`. The extra `&` character screws up the syntax of the `align` environment and so LaTeX crashes. At least, that is my understanding of what is going on, and I could be wrong!

So, the question is whether or not it is possible to force LaTeX to treat the argument in the `[]` case just as it did in the `{}` case (without causing additional problems). In other words, I want to be able to write a macro a-la `\bmat[1&0\\0&1]` that works in aligned environments but retains the square bracket syntax.

CONCLUSION:

Here is the final macro with working `[]` syntax, thanks to egreg (requires `xparse` and must be contained in a separate package file or between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in preamble):

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\mat{}{{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@mat}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\@mat{ g o d() d|| }
{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {
            \IfNoValueTF{#3}
            {
                \IfNoValueTF{#4}
                {()}
                {\begin{vmatrix}#4\end{vmatrix}}
            }
            {
                \begin{pmatrix}#3\end{pmatrix}
                \IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{|#4|}
            }
        }
        {
            \begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}
            \IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{(#3)}
            \IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{|#4|}
        }
    }
    {
        \begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}
        \IfNoValueTF{#3}{}{(#3)}
        \IfNoValueTF{#4}{}{|#4|}
    }
    \ifnum\z@=`{\fi}
}
```

This macro works like an overloaded function with different argument delimiters `{}`, `[]`, `()`, or `||`. There are probably many reasons why this is a terrible idea --- so please, post your comments below. I would like to hear from those who know better than me.

Comment: Is using `{\bmat[1&0\\0&1]}` an acceptable option?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not at all clear why you should want `\bmat` to take its argument in brackets.

Comment: the "inner" `&`s really have to be hidden, so putting them in braces is essential.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful replies! Indeed, it is best to group everything within braces as Scott H. and barbara beeton have suggested. To that end, egreg provided a very sneaky way to insert the grouping braces I need to make it work the way I would like.

Comment: @Sergio I've added to my answer how I would manage the thing, rather than with that complex macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, but I *strongly* recommend you not doing it. You gain nothing in using `[` and `]` as delimiters for a *mandatory* argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bmat{{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@bmat}
\def\@bmat[#1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}\ifnum\z@=`{\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\bmat[1&0\\0&1]$
\begin{align}
M &= \bmat[1&0\\0&1]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result from the example above]

(Note: I have reduced the text width to shorten the output.)

When you understand the trick, you are allowed to use it. :) Hint: look for `\eegroup` in Appendix D of the TeXbook.

---

Defining `\mat` to look for the next token in order to decide a delimiter is, in my opinion, wrong. I'd do like this:

```
\newcommand{\mat}[2][]{\begin{#1matrix}#2\end{#1matrix}}
```

so that

```
\mat{1&2\\3&4}    % no fences
\mat[b]{1&2\\3&4} % brackets
\mat[p]{1&2\\3&4} % parentheses
\mat[v]{1&2\\3&4} % vertical lines
\mat[V]{1&2\\3&4} % double vertical lines
\mat[B]{1&2\\3&4} % braces
```

would do even better, with minimum hassle and better readability.

Personally, I would stick with the long form, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of trick I was looking for. Thank you for the TeXbook reference, it proved to be very enlightening. It also makes me feel better that this trick is in the TeXbook itself! I will append my initial entry with the final implementation the macro I was working on using your trick. I would be interested in your opinion of my macro, as it may be controversial in terms of proper LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @Sergio I've already stated my opinion: you gain nothing (and probably lose something) by using such a syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Why this happens is rather interesting, since of course the raw code

```
\begin{align}
 M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

does work even though the array separators are not between braces.  The reason is that `bmatrix` itself inserts braces specifically to make this work, and by the time scanning has reached the separators, TeX has already read the opening brace and knows that it should protect them.

In your code, it would seem that `\bmat` is replaced with its expansion, which is the above code, before the `&` is read, but in fact, the `&` has already been read at that point: it needs to be picked up by the macro argument grabber.  That is to say, even though the `&` wasn't "executed" it was *seen*, and apparently, TeX will detect the end of an array cell even just when going through tokenization.

Because of this, there is no way to use the normal `\newcommand\bmat[1][]{}` syntax to define a command that "just works" in arrays; egreg's answer shows how you can roll your own that accepts the same syntax but sneakily inserts braces.  It's probably also possible to make a `\catcode` change prior to scanning for the argument that would make `[]` into functional brace characters, but for all that effort, I suggest you redesign your macro not to use an optional argument instead.  As a perhaps compromise, you can place braces around it: `{\bmat[1&0\\0&1]}`, as Scott H. suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and helpful analysis of how LaTeX parses this code! I considered `\catcode` changes but decided to steer clear of anything that might cause confusing `[}` mismatched delimiters and the like.

Comment: Doing with changes to catcodes is made very problematic because of what the amsmath environments like `align` do, they scan their entire contents, hence no catcode can be changed by a macro therein. So simple approaches like `\def\@pmat#1{#1\end{pmatrix}}
\def\pmat{\begin{pmatrix}\catcode`\[=1 \catcode`\]=2 \@pmat}` which do work in inline and display math fail in `amsmath` environments. (there is a backtick texsx formatting problem in my comment that I don't know how to fix)

Comment: @jfbu: I should have known that.  Is there anything that `\@ifmeasuring` doesn't make difficult?

Comment: @RyanReich alas! I got bitten hard by that one some time ago, while attempting to produce a very very lightweight and minimal 'poor man beamer' for my private use to do presentations...

Answer (score 1):

Scanning data inside `\halign` is very special in TeX. Note, that `\halign` 
is primitive implemetation of `bmatrix` or `align` LaTeX environments.

When `\halign` is inside `\halign`, then all works, but macro expansions
must be done carefully. The example from @Ryan's answer

```
\begin{align}
   M &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

does (roughly speaking) this at TeX primitive level:

```
\halign\bgroup #&#\cr 
   M &= \vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &#\cr 1&0\cr 0&1\cr\egroup\egroup 
\cr\egroup
```

The `\begin{bmatrix}` is implemented as a macro which expands to
`\vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &#\cr` (not exactly, but more actions of this
macro is not important for our case) and `\end{bmatrix}` expands to
`\cr\egroup\egroup`. The significant is that the macro `\begin{bmatrix}`
does not read its parameter separated by `\end{matrix}`, that both parts of
this LaTeX environment work "independently". The data
`1&0\cr 0&1` is read at main TeX processor level as `\halign` inside
`\halign` data.

There is totally different situation when a macro with parameter is read
inside data of the outer `\halign`. The main rule when scanning a macro
parameter is:

**The `&` (or `\cr`) is interpreted as `&` (or `\cr`) only if the processing
is inside `{` ... `}` pair**, i.e. inside the pair of characters of catcode 1
and 2. And it is irrelevant if this pair is out of the macro (and does
`\bgroup`...`\egroup` in the typesetting output for example) or this pair 
is used around a macro parameter as syntax rule of reading macro parameters. 
It means that both of these examples work:

```
\def\hh[#1]{\vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &##\cr #1\cr\egroup\egroup}

\halign\bgroup #&#\cr
   M & = {\hh[1&0\cr 0&1]}
\cr\egroup
```

or

```
\def\hh#1{\vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &##\cr #1\cr\egroup\egroup}

\halign\bgroup #&#\cr
   M & = \hh{1&0\cr 0&1}
\cr\egroup
```

On the other hand, when the rule above is not satisfied, then the `&` or
`\cr` is never scanned "as is" in the parameter: it is replaced immediatelly
to the second part of cell declaration finalized by `\endtemplate` which
is forbidden when scanning of parameters. It means that this example does
not work:

```
\def\hh[#1]{\vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &##\cr #1\cr\egroup\egroup}

\halign\bgroup #&#\cr
   M & = \hh[1&0\cr 0&1]
\cr\egroup
```

Moreover, this is not all. All macros are expanded at the beginning of
each data cell until non-expandable and non-space token is found. When
the macro is expanded at this time then `&` is scanned "as is". So, it works:

```
\def\h[#1]{\vbox\bgroup\halign\bgroup &##\cr #1\cr\egroup\egroup}

\halign\bgroup #&#\cr
   M & \expandafter=\h[1&0\cr 0&1]
\cr\egroup
```